# Reporting on Directory Stats

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I need to create a small C# console application to run a report on a directory on my local computer. The report will be an excel document and contain 3 columns including: The name of each folder in the column, if the folder contains any data, if the folder contains data when was it last updated. My current thinking is a small C# console application that reads the directory goes through each folder and performs these tests creating a row at a time. I am fairly new to C# and not sure how I can carry this out. I have tried the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/TestFolder/");

            foreach (string value in filePaths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);



            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to recursively check the subfolders?

Comment: There are no sub folders. I just need to document the name of the folders on the top layer and check if they are empty or contain data

Answer (score 1):

You should:

- Use `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` instead of `Directory` and `File` (provides more info than just a filename)
- Use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles` (enumerates over files instead of retrieveing all at once)
- Do it recursively for every retrieved `FileInfo` which contains `Directory` attribute in its `Attributes` property

so something along the lines of (code straight from head, not compiled and untested):

```
// in your caller method
ProcessFolder(@"C:/TestFolder/");


void ProcessFolder(string path)
{
    foreach (var file in DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles(path))
    {
        if(file.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory == FileAttributes.Directory)
            ProcessFolder(file.FullName); // recursively handle a directory
        else
            Console.Out.Writeline(file.FullName); // handle a file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing nothing to clean up the output here and using a simple string array for the content but feel free to clean it as you like.

Considering no subfolders:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\offTopic");
        var data = di.EnumerateDirectories()
            .Select(a => 
                new string[] 
                {   a.Name, 
                    "" + (a.EnumerateFiles().Count() > 0), 
                    "" + a.EnumerateFileSystemInfos().Max(b => b.LastWriteTime) 
                });

       foreach (var x in data)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", x));
       }

    }
```

Then you will have to write out these contents to a file with a suffix of CSV (comma seperated value) which can be opened by Excel.

Comment: This is returning a System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled Message=Sequence contains no elements exception. Any Idea why?

Comment: @Bradley Perhaps there's no directories in your folder? I was working for me as long as directories existed.